# Object declaration in Java

Tags: java

If I declare an array of objects like one of the following.

> MyClass[ ] myArray;
>
> MyClass myArray[ ];

Are both right?

Comment: @Jeroen Is [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/declare-array-in-java) really a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) of this?

Comment: I don't see any reason why it wouldn't be.

Comment: @Jeroen I read this question as *is one array declaration the same as an apparently different array declaration?* I read that question as *how do I declare an array?* At the very least, the [top-rated (and accepted) answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1200646/2970947) doesn't answer this question at all. There is [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1200648/2970947) that might imply an answer to this question, but it isn't exactly direct.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: it's a canonical Q+A about array declaration and 5 other high voted answers explicitly talk about this, to me that is a certain duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Both expressions are equivalent, of note is that

```
Object[] arr;
Object arr[];
```

create identical bytecode (in Java the first is usually preferred as it is clearer when reading that it's an array). [JLS-10.2. Array Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2) says (in part)

> The [] may appear as part of the type at the beginning of the declaration, or as part of the declarator for a particular variable, or both.